# NSDictionary is null which is populated in previous View Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSLog((@"This is didSelectRowAtIndexPAth"));
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        detailViewController.myDictionary = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]
```

// This MyDictionary NSdictionary is declared in other viewController which is populated here ..

```
        NSLog(@"My Dictionary: This is a MasterView one %@",detailViewController.myDictionary);

        UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        detailViewController = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];

        //The below NSlog is showing the content , its not null still in next viewcontroller same variable showing null content

        NSLog(@"My Dictionary: This is a MasterView two %@",detailViewController.myDictionary);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: You put a dictionary in the first view controller via "`detailViewController.myDictionary =`", but how do you think the dictionary is going to be set or populated for the second view controller?

Comment: Becuz i have inherited that myDictionary object from the next view which is detailViewController .  I am populating it in MasterViewController .

Comment: Why are you instantiating two detailViewControllers? If you have it connected with a segue, the segue instantiates it, you shouldn't even be doing it once, let alone twice.

Comment: What should i do ? Please tell me the code .

Answer (score 0):

Use `PrepareForSegue` for this purpose

`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        DetailViewController * detailViewController = (DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.myDictionary = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:index];
    }`

Answer (score 0):

From did select just use the prepareForSegue method(Hope you have already used.) Set the presenting view controller option via xib or programmatically and just stop there.prepareForSegue will call automatically while presenting the view while using storyboard.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        detailViewController.myDictionary = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];  
}
```

edit you did_select_method and try.